# How to bind to image source?

Tags: sqlite, gridview, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am making a library management software as a personal project. The main page has a frame which navigates to 'YourBooks_View'. YourBooks_View has a GridView which shows the main stuff. The problem is everything binds perfectly except the Cover Image of the book.

This is the SQLite database:
[image: SQLite database]

This is the screenshot of the sample grid view:

[image]

**Note:** the location of the picture exists for sure
[image: proof of existence of the image]

This is 'YourBooks_View.xaml':

```
<StackPanel>

    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Add" 
                      Label="New Book"
                      Click="NewBook_Click"/>

        <AppBarButton Icon="Delete"
                      Label="Remove a Book"
                      Click="DeleteBook_Click"/>
    </CommandBar>

    <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.Books, Mode=OneWay}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Book">

                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Width="200" Height="200" Source="{x:Bind Path=CoverImageLocation, Mode=OneWay}" />

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Path=Title, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind Path=Author, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{x:Bind Path=Quantity, Mode=OneWay}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</StackPanel>
```

This is 'YourBooks_View.xaml.cs':

```
public sealed partial class YourBooks_View : Page
{
    private BooksViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public YourBooks_View()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new BooksViewModel();
    }

    private void NewBook_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void DeleteBook_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

And this is my model(aka BooksViewModel):

```
public class BooksViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Book> books { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Book> Books
    {
        get { return this.books; }

        set
        {
            this.books = value;
        }
    }


    public BooksViewModel()
    {
        books = DataAccess.GetBooks();
    }
}
```

DataAccess is a static class. The GetBooks() method reads a database and returns an Observable Collection of type Book. This is the Book class:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string CoverImageLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the picture is not shown because of sandboxing. I made a new sample project and pasted the image location in the source. It didn't work.

Then, I added that image to assets and then changed the source to "Assets/(Image name.jpg)" and it worked.

Comment: If it is a personal project, you can easily request full file system access. See the last example on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations